# How to replace a tabulation in shell bash linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

to replace a spaces by `,` (as example) in a giving string in shell I use the following command

```
str=${str// /,}
```

How to replace a tabulation by `,` in a string?

I tried

```
str=${str//\t/,}
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stay in your context of using shell internal replacement while expanding variables:

```
str=$'foo\tbar'
echo "${str//$'\t'/,}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tr` for this:

```
$ cat a
hello   how are you?    blabla

$ tr '\t' ',' <a
hello,how are you?,blabla
```